# Expressing composite differentiation in desired manner

Tags: maple

Suppose I have a function like `f=U(g(x))`. When I differentiate this in Maple the result are shown as below

`diff(f,x) = D(U)(g(x))(d/dx(g(x)))`

is displayed.

How I can display result like

```
U[g]g[x]
```

The snapshot of Maple worksheet :

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your wanted output. The brackets, if used after an expression becomes a subscript-operator, much like our `_{}` in LaTeX for indexing. You cannot input `U[g]g[x]` in Maple as it gives an error (missing operator between `[g]` and `g`. Can you elaborate on your problem?

Comment: @Therkel: I have added Maple worksheet snapshot. Actually I don't require to display my results in operator 'D'. I had also posted this question on Mapleprime at: http://mapleprimes.com/questions/219357-How-To-Use-ToJet-Command-When-Differential. When nobody answered it I decided to put it here but in meantime somebody answered my question but not exactly in the form which was expecting like collecting coefficients wrt $U_{\xi}$ etc.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't see your Question on MaplePrimes. I'll go look for it.